# Loading JSON files into BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a JSON file into BigQuery using the bq load command

```
bq load --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON project_abd:ds.online_data gs://online_data/file.json
```

One of the key:value pair in the JSON file looks like - 
**"taxIdentifier":"T"**

The bq load fails with the message -  **Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row
starting at position 713452: Could not convert value to boolean.
Field: taxIdentifier; Value: T** (The JSON is really huge, hence cant paste it here)

I am really confused as to why the autodetect is treating the value T as boolean. I have tried all combinations of creating the table with STRING datatype and then load the table, but due to autodetect, it errors out mentioning -  changed type from STRING to BOOLEAN, if I do not use the autodetect the load succeeds.

I have to use the "autodetect" feature, since the JSON is a result of an API call and the columns may increase or decrease.

Any idea why the value **T** is behaving weird, and how to get around this ?

Comment: Can you just load first row of your json, than export schema, adjust field types and load the full json with your adjusted schema instead of autodetect? it's much more reliable solution

Comment: @AlienDeg- As i mentioned above, when i adjust schema and do not use autodetect, the load succeeds, but for the current requirement, i need to use the autodetect, since the schema of exported JSON may vary.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, that auto-detect accepts "T" as boolean while the JSON reader doesn't. Please file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0. Thanks.

Comment: I have raised a bug with Google. Thanks Hua Zhang